# Turning and turning

Tags: word, pattern

Give a word to complete this sequence:

> rem, curvy, unsee, tharm, jars, up, tiers, tau, run, ran, us, pen, ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you can complete the sequence with:

> **TUNE**

Why?

> The sequence uses the letters of the 8 planets of our solar system (in sequence outwards from the Sun) to form a series of words. Occasionally a letter from the next planet's name is allowed to mix with the letters from the previous, so one letter's overlap is permitted. To demonstrate:
>
>  REM, CURvY, unseE, THARm, Jars, UP, TIERs, tau, rUn, RAN, US, pen, **tune**
>
>  is made using the letters of
>
>  MERCURY, venus, EARTH, mars, JUPITER, saturn, URANUS, nep**tune**

The title refers to:

> The movements of the planets - *turning* on their axes, and completing a *turn* around the Sun.